# How to incrementally increase a variable using an equation in c#?

Tags: c#

sorry if this is quite a simple question, I am just currently in the process of teaching myself C#.

```
            foreach(int n in Enumerable.Range(0, Range)) {

                double s += (1 / Math.Pow(n, 2));
                double s6 = s * 6;
                double pi = Math.Sqrt(s6);

                Console.WriteLine("Pi is equal to {0}", pi);
            }
```

This returns the error "invalid expression term '+='".

I previously wrote a program in python which performs the same task however, I want the line;

```
double s = (1 / Math.Pow(n, 2));
```

to add to itself while the foreach loop is true, in a similar fashion to my python variation;

```
s  += 1/n**2;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `s += (1 / Math.Pow(n, 2));`

Comment: That's what I thought initially, however, this returns "Invalid expression term '+='.

Comment: Show me your code in context, the code that is causing the error.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well the code causing any error seems to just be the line I mention up above. Your line is what I would immediately have assumed is correct, however, Visual studio seems to not be playing ball.

Comment: `s += (1 / Math.Pow(n, 2));` is not in the code sample you posted.  Post  a code sample that reproduces the error.

Comment: Oh apologies, I misunderstood, I have edited the post now to demonstrate. This returns the error "Invalid Expression term '+='"

Comment: Declare your `double s;` variable separately, above the foreach loop.  Then use `s += (1 / Math.Pow(n, 2));` on a single line inside the loop.

Comment: The reason your way doesn't work is that you keep re-declaring the variable inside the loop.

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is a scope issue. s must be declared outside the loop and set an initial value to use += in the intended way.

```
double s = 0;
foreach(int n in Enumerable.Range(0, Range))
{
    s += (1 / Math.Pow(n, 2));
    double s6 = s * 6;
    double pi = Math.Sqrt(s6);
    Console.WriteLine("Pi is equal to {0}", pi);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to initialize it first.

```
double s = 0;
foreach(int n in Enumerable.Range(0, Range)) {

            s += (1 / Math.Pow(n, 2));
            double s6 = s * 6;
            double pi = Math.Sqrt(s6);

            Console.WriteLine("Pi is equal to {0}", pi);
        }
```